# Problem with points or geometry in a model (noob question)

Tags: modeling

I have a model of a car, and there are a couple of broken bits.  Just these two near each other.  But I have no idea where t start looking to fix this distortion. It seems to be just in the rendering, the model shape seems fine, the second picture shows a different angle.

How can I fix this blemish?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:  After some advice from below I was missing around and merged some vertices, and that solved one problem (and it will fix the other too), but now I wonder will that cause issues with anything else? UV's etc?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like wrong direction of "normals". Try enter edit mode, select all, then Recalculate Normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or menu Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside ).

Comment: Recalculate normals only gives me an option for inside, and doing that made it worse (inside ticked)

Comment: @Rob I think you can tag people by using @. 
Anyway, try take a screenshot of their normals, go to Edit mode, Overlays menu, scroll down, and activate showing Face normals and scale the normal size bit bigger. then update the question with that.

Comment: I ended up merging the vertices and that worked, it might have lost a little of the detail, but I am making it for a game asset, so polycount will be reduced eventually anyway.  Seems @ does work for tagging.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have multiple vertices at the same place. Try merging overlapping vertices by going into edit mode, press A to select all, then go to Mesh>Clean up>Merge by distance. Or press F3 and type "Merge by distance".

Comment: A similar result to Recalculating normals, it looks worse, but I think yourself and @lintang_biru are on to something,

PS: how to tag people in comments?